# Pass a struct to a function as a parameter and return a slice of the corresponding struct

Tags: xml, function, go, struct, slice

I am trying to write a function which can be used by different structs.
The return of the function has to be a slice of the corresponding struct.
Thus I need a function which accept a struct as a parameter and return a slice.
My code somehow looks like this but I have no idea how can I wrap it as a function?

```
type name struct{
   FirstName string `xml:"firstName"`
   LastName string `xml:"lastName"`
  }

fileList := TreeTraversal(".")
    var a name
    var b []name 


for i := 0; i < len(fileList); i++{
    fileByte, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fileList[i])

    xml.Unmarshal(fileByte, &a)
    b = append(b, a)
}
```

As far as I know I can pass a struct to a function as an interface, but I have no idea about the return type?

Comment: Writing generic code in Go is hard. Best advice is: Write three non-generic, special implementations and try to combine them afterwards. For your question: I have no idea what your code tries to do.

Comment: @Volker I am trying to read an xml file and append it to a slice. I just want to wirte a function for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function that takes any struct type and returns a slice of it, like:

```
func MakeSlice(s ANY_STRUCT_TYPE) []ANY_STRUCT_TYPE
```

You're looking for generics, which Go doesn't currently support. See [this FAQ entry](https://golang.org/doc/faq#generics).

The Go team is working to [add generics to the language](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-generics-overview.md) - it's a work in progress, and everyone is free to participate in the discussion. Once generics exist, they will provide the solution you seek here.

---

In the meantime, you could use [code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate) or think of a slightly different design for your problem. Some code duplication is OK too, Go doesn't frown upon it as badly as some other languages.

Comment: It seems that the draft design of Type Parameters is accepted. It is fully described here. https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md